# is multicasting enabled on the nexus 5x or 6p?

Tags: android

I am developing a multicasting application and I need to know if multicasting is enabled on the nexus 5x or on the 6p. I currently have the nexus 5 and it is disabled. 
Ref: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=51195

Rooting and recompiling the kernel to enable multicasting isn't an option so I will be purchasing a new device to test with. I would like to use a nexus product, however I need to know if it is enabled.

Could someone who owns one please check if "/proc/net/igmp" exists? any file manager application will work. Sorry, I know it's a simple request. I've googled it, called google support, and looked through an emulator's files all without an answer.

Also If they don't support it, could someone please recommend a device that does support multicasting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I do have a Nexus 5X with Android 6.
ls /proc/net/ig* shows:
igmp6

I also have an old ASUS K010 tablet which have both igmp and igmp6.

I tried multicast using GStreamer in Android. Both work, just make sure you have the right permissions.

Comment: I have an Nexus 5X on 7.0, and can confirm this as well.